# php get_browser possible values

Tags: php, browser

If I user php get_browser(), what are the possible values for the 'browser' key? Assuming I choose to return an array.  I need to determine which browser it is with a switch, but I can't find anywhere on line where it lists possible values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This list is determined by your `browscap.ini` file that is within your PHP config folder. You could also add your own `browscap.ini` file with whatever browser name you want.

Take a look at the docs: https://www.php.net/get_browser